# cassandra long running query paginate

Tags: scala, cassandra, long-integer, pagination

I'm migrating a large table 2 billion lines from a Cassandra cluster v2 to a Cassandra cluster v3
I'm using the paginated mode to read by a block of 1000 lines.
The copy should take 11 days.

Has anyone tried that so long copy?

After 6 hours, I have an error in read:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler - Not retrying statement because it is not idempotent
```

In the code below, it is surely the line with `ma_session.execute`.

Code is in scala.

```
  def paginatedRead(boundStatement:BoundStatement, test:(Row) =>Boolean, f:(Row)=>ResultSetFuture):(Long,Long) ={
    /*
     Cette méthode lit une table en mode paginé d'après le boundstatement
     Une fonction test permet de filtrer les record
     une Fontion f va réaliser une écriture assynchrone
     En sortie, les 2 compteurs nb lectures global et nb insertions
     */
    var page:PagingState =null
    var rsParcel:ResultSet=null

    var newRow:Row=null
    var cptGlobal=0L

    cptExec=0L; cptInsert=0L
    do {
      if (page != null) boundStatement.setPagingState(page)
      rsParcel = ma_session.execute(boundStatement.setFetchSize(fetchSize))
      if (rsParcel !=null) {
        page = rsParcel.getExecutionInfo.getPagingState
      } else page = null
      val nbRows = rsParcel.getAvailableWithoutFetching

      val itParcel = rsParcel.iterator() //. take(nbRows)

      for (i <- 0 until nbRows) {
        newRow=itParcel.next
        if (test(newRow)) {
          addFuture (f(newRow))
        }
        cptGlobal += 1
        if (cptGlobal % 100000==0) Init2.logger.warn("lecture paginated en cours lu: "+cptGlobal+"  ecrit: "+cptInsert)
      }

    }  while (page != null)
    waitFuture
    (cptGlobal,cptInsert)

  }
```

Comment: As the error says, the resulting query you are trying to execute is non-idempotent and that's probably leading to failure on retry (could be due to a temporary timeout during write). If you are sure that the query can be considered idempotent, you can explicitly mark it so and avoid this error. You can find more details about idempotence in Cassandra here - https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/idempotence/. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well effectively, I added setIdemPotent(true) and a retry policy. and also a garbage collector "stop the world"

Comment: After I had a kind of shutdown on a node. At the moment, I'm paginating on a token range to be able to retry on crash